# Pushing to Github from RStudio

Tags: git, r, github, rstudio

What's your git workflow look like when you're working with RStudio?

I want to start using github for source control of my scripts.  I know you can use the command line/terminal to push a repository, but have been unable to find a package for git.  Any suggestion for one?

Alternatively, I could use the `system` command: `system("git push")`

Can anyone suggest a better/more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I don't know of a more elegant way (which is why I'm making this a comment), but this seems to be at the wrong "level."  I don't use R (either scripts or the interactive command line) to edit R scripts.  I use Rgui, R.app, or Emacs/ESS to do my script editing.  It is at the editor (or integrated development environment) that I would expect source control to reside.

Comment: Right - I use RStudio for the most part.  After I'm done with my script and I want to push it - Where is the proper place to do so?  R command line?  In the script editor?  How do you handle this?

Comment: My main development environment is Emacs/ESS.  I know it can interface with git, but I have not explored it.  I do all my git work (stage, add, push, etc.) at a combination of the command line and git-gui.

Comment: Standard reference: http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/11/getting-started-with-git-egit-eclipse.html

Comment: What OS? The normal way to use Git is from the command-line (but not an R command line, a normal shell) or failing that, from an IDE. So you could ask "does RStudio have any Git integration" (and I think [the answer is "not yet"](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions/445-git-integration)), but otherwise, just work in a normal terminal (Linux, OSX) or perhaps msysgit bash (Windows).

Comment: I'm also going to edit your question to reflect your actual needs.

Comment: Poking around on the RStudio development & support sites, it looks like Github integration is built into the development version: I would try http://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/ if you're feeling adventurous

Comment: When I develop R code (using Emacs under Ubuntu), I often have a `git-gui` window open at the same time; when I finished the revision in R scripts, I switch to the Git Gui window and write my commit messages. It is easy to see the (highlighted) changes.

Comment: I believe version control is not yet operational in RStudio. You will have to wait.

Comment: @BenBolker, I've been using the daily build now for a while and it seems relatively stable.

Comment: The RStudio documentation needs to be more explicit about how to put Git in the right path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I seem to remember that the new development version of Rstudio has builtin support for git. If you do not want to use that I myself am perfectly fine with using the command line in a separate console to checkin code. You can also do this from within R using the system command.

ps Daily builds of RStudio can be found here:

http://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/

Comment: The only trouble with the command line option is that a commit message on any R document from within your RStudio project is associated with multiple files in the RStudio project. For example, suppose that I make an edit to a .csv that is in my RStudio project and commit with a message the push to my remote. Well, now that message is associated with an R markdown document in that RStudio project, too.