# Resources for using Git with RStudio

Tags: git, r

Are there any resources (examples, documentation) for using Git specifically with RStudio?

Thank you very much, 
EC

Comment: Perhaps the [RStudio version control documentation](http://rstudio.org/docs/version_control/overview)?

Comment: Note that the version control stuff is brand new -- it's in the preview (v0.95) release announced 2 days ago ... (@JoshUlrich, if you want to promote the comment to an answer I'll upvote it)

Comment: Git integration in RStudio is not brand new, its been around for a couple of months in the daily builds. And yes I have checked the documentation. Not much of a help either. I was hoping for an introduction in version control for the data scientist. There is enough resources for Git for programmers but data analysis are something different. Was hoping for something like that but focused on RStudio.

Comment: It was asked in a previous question: [Pushing to Github from RStudio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511176/pushing-to-github-from-rstudio)